# `auto` specifier type deduction for references

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

Let's consider the following code snippet

```
void Test()
  {
  int x = 0;

  int& rx = x;
  int* px = &x;

  auto apx = px;    // deduced type is int*
  auto arx = rx;    // deduced type is int
  }
```

One could draw an analogy from pointer types expecting that the deduced type of `arx` is `int&`, but it is `int` in fact.

What is the rule in Standard which governs that? What is the reason behind it?
Sometimes I get caught by it in a case like this:

```
const BigClass& GetBigClass();
...
auto ref_bigclass = GetBigClass();   // unexpected copy is performed
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest way to think about it is comparing it to template argument deduction.

Given:

```
template<typename T>
void deduce(T) { }
```

If you call:

```
deduce(px);
```

then the template argument `T` will be deduced as `int*` and if you call

```
deduce(rx);
```

then `T` will be deduced as `int`, not `int&`

You get the same types deduced when using `auto`.

> One could draw an analogy from pointer types expecting that the deduced type of `arx` is `int&`

You'd have to have a fairly confused model of the C++ language to make that analogy. Just because they are declared in syntactically similar ways, as `Type@` with a type and a modifier doesn't make them work the same way. A pointer is a value, an object, and it can be copied and have its value altered by assignment. A reference is not an object, it's a reference to some object.  A reference can't be copied (copying it copies the referent) or altered (assigning to it alters the referent).  A function that returns a pointer returns an object *by value* (the object in question being a pointer object), but a function that returns a reference (like your `GetBigClass()`) returns an object *by reference*. They're completely different semantics, trying to draw analogies between pointers and references is doomed to failure.

Answer (score 14):

Use `auto&`:

```
auto& ref_bigclass = GetBigClass();
```

References are supposed to be transparent: any operation on them happens on the object they refer to, there is no way to 'get' reference itself.

UPD: This is covered in 7.1.6.4/6:

> Once the type of a declarator-id has been determined according to 8.3, the type of the declared variable using the declarator-id is determined from the type of its initializer using the rules for template argument deduction.

And template argument deduction is defined in 14.8.2.1/3:

> If template parameter type P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction.

P.S. Note that this is different for `decltype`: `decltype(rx)` will yield `int&` type (7.1.6.2/4).

Comment: That's clear, but why I don't have to do the same for pointers?

Comment: @Andrey: Because pointers are an object type, references are not. You can have a reference-to-pointer, but not a pointer-to-reference or reference-to-reference.

Comment: @Andrey That's how references are meant to be — by using them you refer to the underlying value, not the reference itself, while pointers are values themselves.