# Auto and reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I've got the following classes:

```
class Card {
    void rotate();
};
class Type1Card : public Card {};
class Type2Card : public Card {};

class Deck {
    Card& draw_card();
};

class Board {
    std::vector<Card const*> cards;
    void put_card(Card const&);
};
```

So the Deck manages cards. It returns **reference** to a card. Then a card can be put on a board - using **const reference** to indicate that it cannot be `nullptr` nor change. As you can see the Board stores pointers to cards (because of polymorphizm).

The problematic code:

```
auto card = deck.draw_card(); // a copy of a card is created
card.rotate();
board.put_card(card); // board will get a pointer to a temporary variable
```

The solutions I see:

1. `draw_card` returns a pointer - ugly because I believe that pointer
   is to indicate that `nullptr` can be returned - not true
2. `put_card` gets a pointer - the same as above why not
3. disable a Card's copy constructor - ugly because it's not a problem of the Card - no reason to limit the Card class

Comment: Are you asking for `auto&`?

Comment: [Probably dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11886930/5267751)?

Comment: Do you really need to have polymorphic card in the first place? This seems like a weird design...

Comment: I think I need. I wanted to put as little of code as possible. But in the Deck I have many more types of cards (some action cards, that cannot be put on the board). And I think that having only one type of card would make it having a lot of unused fields and overcomplicated.

Comment: I don't think this is a good design. I don't know the rules of your game, but usually, what an operation should do does not depend on a single card but on the combination of multiple cards. Your current design will inevitably get you into a big `dynamic_cast` and `typeid` mess everywhere you have two or more `Card&`s and need to decide what game rules to apply to them.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I think that rules are not so important. But you're right that my solution would require `dynami_cast`ing. From the other site when I was looking at the problem I saw many of attributes that are mutually exclusive. When you put a card on the board you can have an interface like `put_card(BoarCard const&)`. But with only one class you have to check inside the `put_card` if it's a `BoardCard`. (Any further comment appreciated:))

Answer (score 2):

You can tell `auto` variables to be references, just write

```
auto& card = deck.draw_card();
```

same for `const` reference

```
const auto& card = deck.draw_card();
```

Comment: OK. It would help. I have only one concern about this (I mean mine) solution: user of the interface needs to know that the `draw_card` returns a reference and that `put_card` needs a valid address. Do you think it is a good design...?

Comment: @user2146414 - The user doesn't need to know. Their compiler will tell them if you design your classes properly.

Comment: @StoryTeller But in my example, where he uses `auto card = ...` compiler doesn't tell him that there is something wrong. Using `auto& card = ...` is a proper one but it requires to be aware about `draw_card` and `put_card`.

Comment: @user2146414 - Because nothing *is* wrong. You didn't prohibit making copies, so the user is not stopped from taking a copy. Like I said *"if you design your classes properly"*.

Comment: @StoryTeller Do you think that deleting the Card's copy constructor would be "a properly designed class"? As you can see in the 3th point in my post I have some doubts. But I'm curious of about you opinion.

Comment: @user2146414 - If the class isn't meant to be copyable, then yes. Exluding copies would be a good design. It's also safer to err on the side of excluding copies than the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to use `auto&`:

```
auto& card = deck.draw_card();
```

so the reference won't be discarded during the type deduction.

---

Also, please, note, that using a `std::vector` of raw pointers:

```
std::vector<Card const*> cards;
```

is not the best idea. As your cards come to `Board` outside, `Board` itself does not control the lifetime of the cards it refers to. In this case it is extremely easy to get dangling pointers and move to the UB area.

You should probably consider just copying cards to the `Board` class or start using smart pointer - whatever suits better to your program.

Comment: I think your comment about storing pointers is essential. The case of not controlling cards lifetime is intentional. I wanted the Deck to control cards' lifetime. And I intentionally passed a reference (raw pointer) as an indicator of not owning "pointer". So maybe copying a card would be a better option...