# C++ map::find & map::at performance difference

Tags: c++11, thread-safety, stdmap

I was grading some exercises and at a specific program although the algorithm seemed correct it would be too slow (and I mean ***too*** slow). The program was accessing a map using `map::at` (introduced in C++11). With a minimum change of replacing `at` with `find` (and fixing the syntax) the same program would be really fast (compared to the original version).

Looking at cplusplus.com both methods claim to have the same complexity and I couldn't see why one would be different from the other (other than API reason, not throwing an exception, etc).

Then I saw that the description in the section about data races is different. But I don't fully understand the implications. Is my assumption that `map::at` is thread safe (whereas `map::find` is not) and thus incurring some runtime penalties correct?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

Edit

Both are in a loop called 10.000.000 times. No optimization flags. Just `g++ foo.cpp`. Here is the diff (arrayX are vectors, m is a map)

```
<               auto t = m.find(array1.at(i));
<               auto t2 = t->second.find(array2.at(i));
<               y = t->second.size();
<               cout << array.at(i) << "[" << t2->second << " of " << y << "]" << endl;
---
>               auto t = m.at(array1.at(i));
>               x = t.at(array2.at(i));
>               y = m.at(array1.at(i)).size();
>               cout << array.at(i) << "[" << x << " of " << y << "]" << endl;
```

Comment: "*other than API reason, not throwing an exception, etc*" - that impacts the performance. Especially if it's the critical part of the algorithm. Thread safe versions are also a touch slower

Comment: I don't have any exceptions occurring in both versions. So there is no "active" exception handling happening, no stack unwound etc.

Comment: You are mistunderstanding the handling of the exceptions. Consider `std::vector`s `operator[]` and `at` functions. Both of them are `O(1)` in speed. Both of them give you access to the `n`th element. But if you provide an incorrect index, `operator[]` behaviour is undefined. Probably it will give you a garbage reference. `at`, on the other hand, every time you call it, it *performs a check* - simple `if` statement to see whether the index is out of bounds. It if is, an exception is thrown. If no exceptions are thrown and the index is valid, you '*lose*' some time to perform the check

Comment: Probably I didn't make the difference in time clear. In numbers it's 50sec versus hours. I don't (I hope) think a simple if would cause such a difference.

Comment: That depends on how many times you actually call `at`. I see you measured the time carefully. Good! Which compiler flags did you use to optimise your code and in what way was it built (debug or release)? Without those information, the measurements and comparisons are close to useless, unfortunately

Comment: I edited the original post with more info

Comment: "*No optimization flags*" - there lies your problem. It's pointless to measure the performance, if you are not using optimisations. In real life, you will *always* use them in your work. I will also point out that you should build your project as *release*, not *debug*

Comment: I don't see why optimization is my problem. I am comparing two different methods that seem to do similar things. The time difference is order of magnitude. We are not doing microbenchmarking here. So, the original question, is `map::at` thread safe? And if that holds, would it explain such stark differences?

Comment: Yes, it is thread safe, **because it's a `const` method** and since `C++11` the standard guarantees that each `const` method is thread safe. And yes, the additional check could explain such difference in performance. Alongside it not being `noexcept`

Comment: What is your mapped type? I am pretty sure that for `auto t` in your code, `mapped_type` is deduced (and not a reference), which leads to `mapped_type` copies. Try with `auto& t`.

Comment: Wow! That was the culprit. Changing `auto t` to `auto& t` and keeping the `map::at` it runs really fast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance difference you are observing can be attributed to **object copying**.

```
auto t = m.at(array1.at(i));
```

According to [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) rules (same are applied for the `auto` specifier), in the above statement, `t` is deduced to `mapped_type`, which triggers an object copy.

You need to define `t` as `auto& t` for it to be deduced to `mapped_type&`.

Related conversation: [`auto` specifier type deduction for references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886930/auto-specifier-type-deduction-for-references)

Comment: My bad. I thought that `auto` would be more sophisticated and would pay close attention on the exact method signature (include the reference).

Comment: Well, C++ pages are definitely not an easy (or pleasant for that matter) read!

Comment: @GeorgeKastrinis, but then it wouldn't be as flexible. By default it always produces a non-const non-reference copy, and you can override those 2 features easily. If the rule tracked the type of the function you called, then you would always have to go look at the function to decide if you needed to add an override to make it non-const or a copy, and in fact the language doesn't easily give you those two things (unless you go through a type traits converter, which is not pretty). OK in a few cases this is nonsense, like a function reference is still a reference.